# g_utf8_collate() not found in GLib-2.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 (LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, glib

I've installed in my Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev-bin
```

but this small test code fails to link:

```
cat -n test.c
     1  #include <stdio.h>
     2  #include <glib.h>
     3  
     4  int main()
     5  {
     6      char *p1 = "foo";
     7      char *p2 = "bar";
     8      int rc = 0;
     9  
    10      rc = g_utf8_collate(p1, p2);
    11      printf("g_utf8_collate(p1, p2) = %d\n", rc);
    12  }
cc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lglib-2.0 test.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc583STn.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `g_utf8_collate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

On all my other systems (SuSE Linux, FreeBSD) it links file, ofc with other `-I` and `-L` dirs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got to know that the order of the source file and the linker options do matter. It works fine like this:

```
cc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include test.c -lm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lglib-2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0) test.c
```

`pkg-config` exists to provide the right compiler and linker flags for dependencies, so that you don’t have to specify them manually.

Comment: $ cc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0) test.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccrGxQq4.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `g_utf8_collate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: If `pkg-config` is providing cflags and libs in the wrong order then something is wrong with your distribution/installation and you should file a bug against it.

Comment: No. Your usage is wrong. It should be: cc $(pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0) test.c $(pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)

Comment: I have tested my usage and it’s fine (and has worked fine for 20 years) with my compiler. Are you using a compiler other than gcc or clang?

Comment: gcc -v 2>&1 | grep 'gcc version' ; echo gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0) test.c ; gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0 test.c
gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 
gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0 test.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccKDKaPI.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `g_utf8_collate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Hmm, odd. Perhaps this is a difference in the command line handling which only shows up on aarch64?

Comment: grep PRE /etc/os-release ; gcc -v 2>&1 | grep 'gcc version' ; echo gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0) test.c ; gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0 test.c
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 
gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0 test.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccO90LCh.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `glib_minor_version' ...